# Customizing Issue in Open Edx Tutor

Tags: docker, openedx

I have 2 projects related to open edx docker based platform: one to run it via tutor (the project is called tutor) that I cloned it via this link:"https://github.com/openedx/edx-platform.git"
and one for the customizing the platform, I used our own repo where we have everything related to the customization of the edx-platform( called edx-platform).
I made changes to the edx-platform(modified the about page(about.html)) (in the edx-platform project).

I re-builded the docker images and started the project again but the changes aren't displaying on the edx-platform site.
The version of the tutor project is: 16.1.5.
And Am Not running it in production mode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.